# How to hide element in a Android Webview app using a Bootstrap website?

Tags: javascript, android, twitter-bootstrap-3, webview

I've made a Android webview app of my bootstrap 3 website.

Now I want to place something like this in the header of the website

```
<div class="visible-xs">{google play icon to promote the app}</div>
```

This element should be visible when opening the website on a mobile. But hidden when opening the webview app.

The ideal solution would be if this can be done by changing/adding a code on the website, rather then in the webview app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

I mean something like this:

```
.visible-xs{
    visibility: visible;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {

    .visible-xs {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure is this would be a valid solution as it may hide other elements also. Thanks though

Comment: You are right, it will be hide also other elements having the same class. But you can define a specific class or id just for the google play icon